# Mono libmono-btls-shared missing

Tags: mono

When upgraded to mono 4.8.0.495 on an armel SBC running Debian.  I received the following error when trying to install certificates:

System.DllNotFoundException: /usr/lib/../lib/libmono-btls-shared.so

I tried to install libmono-btls-interface4.0-cil however it does not seem to exist for armel.

Comment: Having the same issue on a Raspberry Pi 3 with all the latest updates

Comment: Running into the same right now. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: updating to the latest version fixed it for me.